# Fourier Transform of an acceleration signal containing engine orders

Tags: fourier-transform

I am trying to understand how to evaluate this equation in the context of  acceleration data which contain engine orders

$a^{f_{e}^{crit}}(f)=\sum_{o}^{K}A^{o,f_{e}^{crit}}\mathscr{F}(cos(2\pi \cdot f_{e}^{crit} \cdot o \cdot t))$

$a^{f_{e}^{crit}}$ is the acceleration, $f_{e}^{crit}$ is the critical engine speed, 
$A^{f_{e}^{crit}}$ is the acceleration expressed as a complex number and $o=0.5,1,1.5,....$ are the engine orders

My confusion arises when I try to understand how it is possible to sum the time histories of the engine orders and then apply a fourier transform to frequency domain. 
I am not actually sure is it possible to have a time history of an engine order...

Any clarifications will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "engine order"?  And is this acceleration signal the vehicle acceleration, or is it an accelerometer mounted to an engine block that's sensing vibration?

Comment: The engine orders are the harmonics of vibration described by N multiples of engine speed. It is an accelerometer mounted on the engine

Comment: That looks like a very peculiar way to express a fairly standard inverse Fourier transform, very possibly by an author who does not want to introduce the student to Dirac impulses.  I'm also pretty sure that it's erroneous (because $\mathcal{F}^{-1} \left \lbrace i \mathcal{F} \left \lbrace \cos \omega t \right \rbrace \right \rbrace \ne \sin \omega t$).  Can you reference the text out of which it comes?

Comment: You will find it on pg15 eqn 2.36. The description starts on pg14 via this link...http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/record.jsf?pid=diva2%3A1222603&dswid=466

Comment: It's a student thesis.  Even given that it's a Master's thesis, it's by some guy who doesn't have to get all the signal-processing 'i's dotted and 't's crossed.  I think  you just need to accept that the guy is -- probably unknowingly -- playing fast and loose with the math.  He goes off the rails at equation 2.37, but he makes complimentary mistakes going from 2.37 to 2.38, so the final answer is correct.